# How to use the regex matching pattern shall find the part of each word that begins at the first letter and continues to the first vowel?

Tags: regex

I am studying regex right now. This is my question:
"I think that I shall never see a poem lovely as a tree. - Joyce Kilmer"
Use the regex to return "I, thi, tha, I, sha, ne, se, a, po, lo, a, a, tre, Jo, Ki"

Comment: See [What does the regex mean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean).

Comment: What regex that you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with

```
\b[^\sAEIOUaeiou]*[aeiouAEIOU]
```

http://regexr.com/3gvo3

to break it down

`\b` is a word boundary so it searches for whole words

`[^\sAEIOUaeiou]*` will match any character that isnt a space or a vowel

`[aeiouAEIOU]` will match the first occurence of a vowel in the word